# Translating time between timezones in Excel using lookup reference data rather than human input timezone offsets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, api

I have an Excel workbook that tracks work time for staff members. Staff are located in multiple countries. In the Excel workbook, there is a column for the worker’s city, the local time, and the time in London.

Is there an Excel technique that can be used to translate the local time into London time via a formula?

Alternatively, is there an API anywhere that can be called to achieve this translation, and which we could enable within the Excel workbook via code?

Thanks.

Keith

Comment: Do you want the time in **GMT** or **BST** ??

Comment: Would [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-time-to-time-zone) information be helpfull?

Comment: To Gary: Either BST or GMT is fine. But the problem is finding a function that will look up the staff member's local city and convert the time to GMT or BST.

Comment: To JvdV: I am aware of that Excel function. The problem is that I do not want to enter the offset from the staff member's local time zone to London manually. I want a function that will do this for me, based upon the staff member's local city column.

Comment: If you're looking for a solution using VBA or API, I would suggest you asking this question in StackOverflow instead of Superuser for suitable response: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: There isn't a formula to translate location to time zone.  That wouldn't even be possible because timezone boundaries are loaded with exceptions.  You basically need a table of cities and their timezones (and that constantly changes a little), then do a simple lookup.

Comment: @fixer1234 is right. You may also need to regularly update this table, or use some fancy formulas to account for standard vs daylight savings time not being the same everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, especially fixer1234 and cybernetic.nomad. I was afraid that a table of cities would be required.